# Log file size limit

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logging, cron, log-files

I have a script which runs every 5 minutes by cron, with `>> path/logfile.log` appended to store the output. Let's say I have this script running several years; do I have to worry about this file getting to big, i.e. do I have to manually shorten it down regularly?

Answer (score 3):

> do I have to worry about this file getting to big,

Well, assuming you've not invented an infinite storage device, then yes this is something good to think about.

> i.e. do I have to manually shorten it down regularly?

Look into `logrotate`, which is a standard method of maintaining log files that ships with every distribution.